# Issue getting text to align with text field?

Tags: html, css

i'm having a small issue getting my text to line up with my text fields for some reason when I float the text to left and the text fields to right everything goes crazy so I've just left it with the text float left and nothing on the text fields. Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?

```css
#form {
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#formName {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#formName p {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #565f65;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#formInput {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#tbName {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #555;
}

#tb {
  width: 40%;
}

#tb input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
}

#cb {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 40%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#cbName {
  color: #555;
}

#submitBtn {
  padding-left: 40%;
}

.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #2f8fcb;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<form action="Register.php" method="post">
  <div id="form">
    <div id="formName" }>
      <p>Register</p>
    </div>

    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Username</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Email</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Password</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Confirm Password</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="cb">
        <input name="checkTOS" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <div id="cbName">
        <p>I Agree The
          <font color="#799dba">Terms Of Services</font>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="submitBtn">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="REGISTER">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You haven't told us what you *want* to happen. You just said you want them to align, and that they're "going crazy". "Align" is a very general term. What is your *desired* result? That being said, I think hink you've gone a bit overkill in terms of elements here... You may have an easier time manipulating and positioning your text/textboxes if each item on the page isn't so deeply nested.

Answer (score 1):

You could mind in work better with the float property building a line specific UI.

You have to mind that float columns must need a `clear: both` to stop the float effects applied into the elements when you finish the style. I've set it to the `#formInput` for example.

I've applied a `float: left` to the textbox column and cleared the `<p>` element margin, the line vertical space could be better controlled by the line element (that must be a class, not an ID.. you can use a lot of this by this way).

Hope it helps in an alternative way.

```css
#form {
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#formName {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#formName p {
  padding-top: 10px; 
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px; 
  color: #565f65;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#formInput {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  clear: both; /* To clear the float influences to the next line */
}

#tbName {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #555;
}

#tbName p {
  margin: 0;
}

#tb {
  width: 40%;
  float: left /* to fit with the label column */
}

#tb input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
}

#cb {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 40%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#cbName {
  color: #555;
}

#submitBtn {
  padding-left: 40%;
}

.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #2f8fcb;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<form action="Register.php" method="post">
  <div id="form">
    <div id="formName" }>
      <p>Register</p>
    </div>

    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Username</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Email</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Password</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Confirm Password</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="cb">
        <input name="checkTOS" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <div id="cbName">
        <p>I Agree The
          <font color="#799dba">Terms Of Services</font>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="submitBtn">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="REGISTER">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a display flex to the formInput id did the trick, also remove the floats on the other elements. You might want to consider reducing the amount of nested elements inside the form so its not that complex for layout.

```css
#form {
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#formName {
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#formName p {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #565f65;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#formInput {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#tbName {
  width: 40%;
  
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #555;
}

#tb {
  width: 40%;
}

#tb input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
}

#cb {
  
  padding-left: 40%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#cbName {
  color: #555;
}

#submitBtn {
  padding-left: 40%;
}

.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #2f8fcb;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#formInput{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<form action="Register.php" method="post">
  <div id="form">
    <div id="formName">
      <p>Register</p>
    </div>

    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Username</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Email</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Password</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="tbName">
        <p>Confirm Password</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tb">
        <input name="Username" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="cb">
        <input name="checkTOS" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <div id="cbName">
        <p>I Agree The
          <font color="#799dba">Terms Of Services</font>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formInput">
      <div id="submitBtn">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="REGISTER">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the text to be position to the left of the text box.

Try settings the divs that surround the input and p tags to include the css **display: inline-block** and remove the floats.